# Unable to print multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Below is my javascript code:

```
var newData =[];
for(var j = 0; j<dates.length;j++){
    newData = [[dates[j],close[j]]];
}
document.write(newData[1]);
```

When I tried to print `newData[2]` and onwards, it shows `undefined`.
Only `newData[1]` shows me the actual value.
Is there anything wrong in the code above ? 
I am sure that `dates` and `close` array contains all the values needed

Comment: Don't use `document.write`!

Comment: Please show us the values of `dates` and `close`. It would also be helpful for you to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Looks like you overwrite your `newData` array with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Your top-level array is only one element, so newData[1] would be undefined, newData[0] would be an array containing dates[j] and close[j].

Answer (score 4):

You should `push` one array into outside array like this:

```
var newData =[];
for(var j = 0; j<dates.length;j++){
    newData.push([dates[j],close[j]]);
}
```

Otherwise you will overwrite you `newData` array in each loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite existing data of specific key, here is how you can do it:

```
for(var j = 0; j<dates.length;j++){
    newData[j] = [dates[j],close[j]];
}
```

If you want to create an array from the scratch, do as @suvroc suggested